# Excluding a Form From in Visual Studio and replacing it with the new one

Tags: visual-studio-code

We have a Visual studio 2017 with a HomePage (Main) This form has a menuStrip with some sub-menu items. Recently, we removed one of these items thinking it should not be inside the menuStrip. By going to the project Solution, we did not delete that form but excluded it from the project. After creating the new form with a different name, we copied the same working code into this new form with the same CTLs name.
Now, the issue is that the new form not functioning as used to! This form is a password recovery form that will ask for user email and user pin #, then it will let the user create a new password. Of course, it is connected to SQL Server to check and verify user correct responses.

Any suggestions why our new form is not working when it was working before? Did we miss something here?

Appreciated your help!

Comment: tagging it with `visual-studio-code` will not give you the right audience

Comment: If actual coding required to view, please let us know. Although the code was working fine, we can provide more details about how it was written.

Comment: change your tags otherwise you will not get an answer, the only useful find I get for CTL is Visual Basic. Why keep the old stuff when you only change a little bit, don't you use version control